# What is this python for loop actually doing

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

I'm trying to port some code from Python to R and I've come across a use of `for` in the Python code I've not seen before and I can't find answers by googling:

The line of code is:
`logp = [theta[np.newaxis, ...] for theta in thetai]`

I understand the `theta[np.newaxis, ...]` part, but I cannot figure out the `for` clause after it for a few reasons

I've made a small reproducible example here:

```
import numpy as np
theta = np.random.rand(5, 2, 2, 3)
thetai = theta[0]

logp = [theta[np.newaxis, ...] for theta in thetai]
```

Produces this output:

```
logp
Out[406]: 
[array([[[0.305, 0.071, 0.483],
         [0.005, 0.627, 0.24 ]]]),
 array([[[0.648, 0.524, 0.254],
         [0.257, 0.367, 0.796]]])]
```

I don't understand a couple of things.
1. What is the for clause doing - is it a means to subset the array?
2. How can you for `theta` in `thetai` - when `thetai` is actually a subset of `theta` ?

Appreciate any assistance here, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please reopen this question. Only part of the problem is answered by the list comprehension question referred to. The second part of the question is about why ```for bigthing in smallthing``` works. This seems to be linked to the list comprehension expression, as expanding the for loop expression seems to change the behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called list comprehension in python. The basic idea is to write statements in more compact way. 
Instead of

```
arr = []
for x in range(10):
  arr.append(x)
```

we can write

```
arr = [ x for x in range(10)]
```

Check out more on this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Thanks. But also in my example I dont' get the order of the for loop - it is ```for bigthing in smallthing``` but somehow works ?

Comment: @user2498193 I don't know much about numpy but theta has shape of (2,3) and thetai has (2,2,3) which clearly means thetai is a 'bigthing' and theta is a 'smallthing'. You can always use print statements and theta.shape to check your arrays and dimensions. Hope it helps.

Comment: ```theta``` has shape (5,2,2,3) as declared in the ```np.random.rand``` statement. The list comprehension code maintains those dimensions.
Note that when I express the code in a for loop ```for theta in thetai:
    theta[np.newaxis, ...]``` this changes the shape of theta somehow to be (2,3). So either I've coded that wrong, or the list comprehension expression is evaulated differently somehow

Comment: I will just open a new question for this 

Comment: @user2498193 Sorry I couldn't answer your question properly. You said you are doing `for bigthing in smallthing`, but you aren't. theta inside `for theta in thetai` has shape (2,3). But original theta has shape of (5, 2, 2, 3). This means these thetas aren't same. In fact, `for x in something` denotes that 'x' is a temporary variable inside the loop. Your original theta has global scope to the module.

Comment: No thank you for your efforts! Yes someone explained that to me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61866304/unusual-list-comprehension-behaviour/61866901#61866901
I simply didn't realise the theta in the for loop was a diffferent theta. I would not choose theta for this iterative loop counter myself!