# Unusual list comprehension behaviour

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm trying to port some code from Python to R and I've come across a list comprehension I cannot fully understand. Here is a toy example analogous to the code

```
import numpy as np
theta = np.random.rand(5, 2, 2, 3)
thetai = theta[0]

logp = [theta[np.newaxis, ...] for theta in thetai]
```

If I run and print the results I get:

```
print(logp)
[array([[[0.779, 0.461, 0.766],
        [0.245, 0.189, 0.045]]]), array([[[0.229, 0.288, 0.173],
        [0.011, 0.541, 0.528]]])]
```

Ok output is a list of two arrays. What I cannot understand is the `for theta in thetai` clause. Why? Because `theta` is a bigger array than `thetai`. `Theta` has shape (5,2,2,3) but `thetai` has shape (2,2,3). So what is the list comprehension actually doing when the code says `for biggerthing in smallerthing` ???

Comment: Ohhhh ok ‍♂️.That was confusing variable name choice. Yes when I tried to make a for loop version I was noticing the overwriting and that confused me more.
So I'm still unclear on what this line of code actually achieves however. Seems like it simply reshapes thetai from array (2,2,3) to a list of 2 arrays (1,2,3) ?

Comment: Looking at the following lines I believe that is what the aim. @WeavingBird1917 if you want to put your comment as the answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theta` refers to a new local variable within the list comprehension; it does not refer to the array `theta` anymore. Note that the difference between a `for` loop and a list comprehension is that the variable `i` in the list comprehension is a local variable, whereas the `i` in the for loop will overwrite the outer variables too. See:

```
i = -1
[i for i in range(10)]  # Outputs [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(i)  # Prints -1

i = -1
for i in range(10):
    pass
print(i)  # Prints 9
```